# Symbolic (analytic) solution to a nonlinear algebraic equation

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have obtained a set of three nonlinear algebraic equations resulting from conservation laws for momentum and kinetic energy.
$$
\begin{align}
m_1 V_1 \cos(\theta) + m_2 V_2 \cos(\alpha) & = m_1 V_0 \tag{1}\\
m_1 V_1 \sin(\theta) - m_2 V_2 \sin(\alpha) & = 0 \tag{2}   \\
m_1 V_1^2 + m_2 V_2^2  &= m_1 V_0^2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

with the substituion $r = m_2/m_1$, they're simplified into

$$
\begin{align}
V_1 \cos(\theta) + r V_2 \cos(\alpha) & = V_0 \tag{4} \\
V_1 \sin(\theta) - r V_2 \sin(\alpha) & = 0   \tag{5} \\
V_1^2 + r V_2^2  &= V_0^2  \tag{6} \\
\end{align}
$$

$m_1, m_2$ are the colliding masses, $V_0$ is the velocity of $m_1$ before the collision, and whereas $\theta , \alpha$ are the scattering angles and $V_1,V_2$ are the speeds of $m_1,m_2$ after collision respectively. The **unknowns** are $V_1$, $V_2$, and $\alpha$ (displayed as $\cos(\alpha)$), all remaning parameters are given.

My attempt to get an analytic solution is as follows:

- square Eqs. 4 & 5
- then multiply squared Eq.4 with $\sin(\theta) \sin(\alpha)$, and squared Eq.5 with $\cos(\theta) \cos(\alpha)$
- add resulting equations to get rid of cross multiplied terms.
- Finally replace $V_0^2$ at the resulting RHS, with LHS of the Eq.6

This way, I get an equation (or equality?) between $V_1^2$ and $V_2^2$, after which I do equate their coefficients to get a **constraint** for th unknown angle $\alpha$ :

$$ \cos(\alpha) \sin(\alpha) = \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) / r  \tag{7} $$

Eq.7 apparently eliminates the unknown angle $\alpha$, and then I would use Eqs 4 & 5, which become two linear equations in two remaning unknown $V_1$ and $V_2$, by substituting the found value $\alpha$ from Eq.7.

After this solution procedure, the result satisfies Eqs. 4 & 5, but not Eq.6? What's wrong in this solution procedure?

I've used a symbolic package to get an alternate answer, and it seems that the angle $\alpha$ I found using Eq.7 is different from the one returned from the symbolic package...

Any help in either explaining what I have done wrong above, or how to solve this set of nonlinear equations will be appreciated.

Comment: seems dimensionally incorrect

Comment: it's ok now, thanks

Comment: With the help of MATHEMATICA 
`Solve[{v1 Cos[t] + r v2 Cos[a] == v0, v1 Sin[t] - r v2 Sin[a] == 0, v1^2 + r v2^2 == v0^2}, {v1, v2, a}] /. {C[1] -> 0} // FullSimplify`

Comment: @Cesareo Hi, thank you! But I was asking for a solution by hand, I've already used MATLAB to get a symbolic answer but I wonder (want to learn) why my own solution procedure yields a wrong solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

As

$$
\left(V_0-V_1\cos\theta\right)^2+\left(V_1\sin\theta\right)^2=r^2V_2^2
$$

or

$$
V_0^2-2V_0V_1\cos\theta+V_1^2=r^2V_2^2
$$

solving

$$
\cases{
V_0^2-2V_0V_1\cos\theta+V_1^2=r^2V_2^2\\
V_1^2+rV_2^2=V_0^2
}
$$

for $V_1,V_2$ and after that, for $\alpha$

Comment: Thank you, that's very nice! This shows not only how to solve it, but also how to do it the better way than I was trying. Indeed I've already figured out my mistake too: I have, shamefully, regarded the equation $a V_1^2 + bV_2^2 = c V_1^2 + d V_2^2$ to imply $a=c$, and $b=d$ to reach my constraint on $\alpha$ in Eq.7. What a shame ! :-) Instead, in the corrected form, from Eqs 1 & 2, I define $V_1$ and $V_2$ in terms of $\alpha$, and then plug them into Eq.3 to get the correct relation to solve for $\alpha$, then insert $\alpha$ into Eqs. 1 & 2 for a linear system solution of $V_1$ and $V_2$.